# Firebase storage onSuccess not being called when image is added

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to save data to firebase with the following structure

```
root
--clothing
----clothingImgDownloadUrl
------title
------category
```

As I understand I need to make a reference to the path in my database where I want to save the new data.

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
assert app != null;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
mClothingRef = mDatabase.getReference("clothing");
```

I want to add new clothing using the clothing reference created above

```
mClothingRef.child(clothingImgDownloadUrl).setValue(clothing);
```

However the code above is only ran once the clothing image is uploaded to firebase storage and its download url is returned to the app where it can be used as the unique identifier for the entries in the firebase database. Below is the code to upload the image to firebase storage.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference(FIREBASE_STORAGE_CLOTHING_REFERENCE);
StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
photoRef.putFile(mSelectedImageUri)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                Log.d("ADMIN_ACTIVITY", "Called");
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                assert downloadUrl != null;
                String imageUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
                Clothing clothing = new Clothing(imageUrl, title, mCategory);
                mClothingRepository.addClothing(clothing);
             }
         });
```

When the app is ran and I add a clothing item from the admin part of the app, the image is indeed added to the firebase storage, however the Log call in the last code snippet is not called. Surely if the image is added then the `onSuccess` listener should be called and then the `addClothing` method should be ran.

Why is the `onSuccess` listener not being called and am I saving to the real time database correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the activity-scoped form of [addOnSuccessListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnSuccessListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)).  The documentation notes that:

> The listener will be automatically removed during onStop()

The most likely explanation for the listener not being called is that the activity passed as the first argument (`this`) has completed and its `onStop()` method called.  To confirm that this is the case, remove the `this` argument and see if the listener is called.

Comment: Now that I have removed the this as the first argument, my application crashes. In the logcat there is no information about the crash.

Comment: Does the logcat show the output of this statement before the crash? `Log.d("ADMIN_ACTIVITY", "Called")`

Comment: Actually the log cat does give information on the crash. Invalid Firebase Database path: Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', This occurs when the addClothingMethod is called

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use some or all of the downloadUrl to build a Firebase reference.  That's not safe.  The URL can contain `.` and other characters not valid in a Firebase reference path.  At least this confirms the listener is getting called, so your initial question is resolved.

Comment: Note that while using a non-activity-scoped listener explained the mystery of why the listener was not being called, it may not be the right long-term solution.  Uploads of larger files can take tens of seconds or longer.  If done in an activity, there is the risk that the activity will be destroyed before the upload completes.  The user could back out of the activity or rotate the device, causing a config change.  You may need to re-think your design or put in guards to ensure the activity remains alive until the upload completes.